# NameError (uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::ParameterFilter): How to fix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, activesupport

I made Comment function in my app.

And I uploaded this to github.

then I didn't upload vendor(ignore vendor) and git rm --chached -r vendor/bundle2.

Maybe I did that, I can't see Post view in my app.

error is (in browser)

```
NameError in PostsController#index
uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::ParameterFilter
Extracted source (around line #80):
78  # If the constant was actually loaded, something else went wrong?
79  raise(e) if from_mod.const_defined?(const_name)
80  CoreExt::ActiveSupport.without_bootsnap_cache { super }
81  end
82
83  # Signature has changed a few times over the years; easiest to not
```

error log is

```
NameError (uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::ParameterFilter):

vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:80:in `block in load_missing_constant'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active
.
.
.
```

to reference this article(https://github.com/aserafin/grape_logging/issues/66)
but it won't work.

Anyone knows this error?

thank you for reading this.

Comment: That error is deep in the bowels of rails.  You probably didn't include a dependency that is needed.  Does it run locally?

Comment: Thanks comment. Yes this is local development environment.

Comment: Suggest rolling back to your last good version.

Comment: The joy of source code control.

Comment: >>dbugger    sorry I thought that I commented. But Not. Your suggestion is very good.I tried rollback and it work! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After trying several solutions without success such as the one referenced (https://github.com/aserafin/grape_logging/issues/66), I updated my rails version from 5.2.4.3 to 6.0.3 and it solved my problem.

Comment: sorry Ldk. I missed your answer!
Thanks!